# Strapi change favicon v4+

Tags: node.js, strapi, favicon

How to change favicon in Strapi. the icon I have converted but can't change the default strapi logo. I have changed the other logos from settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. place the icon in this path

> src/admin/extensions/favicon.ico

2. then in app.js

> src/admin/app.js

```
import favicon from './extensions/favicon.ico';

const config = {
  head: {
    favicon: favicon,
  },
};

const bootstrap = app => {
  console.log('bootstrap', app);
};

export default {
  config,
  bootstrap,
};
```

And all set!